# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable even though it says it's a string, why is that so?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

The goal of this function is to check whether an Amazon item is unavailable or not.

```
def check(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}
        page = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

        doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
        XPATH_AVAILABILITY = '//div[@id ="availability"]//text()'
        RAw_AVAILABILITY = doc.xpath(XPATH_AVAILABILITY)
        AVAILABILITY = ''.join(RAw_AVAILABILITY).strip()
        if any(re.match(r'unavailable', str(AVAILABILITY), re.IGNORECASE)):
            return "UNAVAILABLE"
        else:
            return "AVAILABLE"
```

I checked the `type()` of the `AVAILABILITY` variable (it's string) and it looks like this when the item is unavailable:

```
Currently unavailable.
        
        
    
    
    
    



    
    
         
        
        
            We don't know when or if this item will be back in stock.
```

and like this (type: string) when it's available:

`In Stock.` or `In stock.`

That's why I opted for the regex for detection of "unavailable" in the output. But the error says:

> File "scra.py", line 68, in
>
> if any(re.match(r'unavailable', check(i), re.IGNORECASE)):
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

It never outputs a "None" ever that's why I'm surprised. Please help me solve this.

Comment: I tried re.findall, and there's an error. I tried search, and the same thing happens.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I tried search instead of match, error occurred: TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not iterable

Answer (score 2):

`any(x)` *iterates* over `x` and returns `True` if it finds an element that evaluates true, or `False` if it gets to the end.

`re.match` returns either a `Match` object if a matches is found or `None`.

Your content must not match the regular expression, `re.match` returns `None` and `any` can't iterate over it.

Comment: Even if it does, match objects are not iterable either I'm pretty sure